# Changing decimal separator in VBA (not only in Excel)

Tags: vba, excel

Type in A1 cell `=1/10`

Run this macro:

```
Sub ChangeDecimalSeparator()
    Application.DecimalSeparator = "#"
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
    MsgBox Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

Apparently now in cell A1 you can see that the decimal separator has been changed to new character #. Why on earth VBA still sees it as your default seperator, although you have changed it (I mean the MsgBox).

Why I need it? My default separator is , (comma). I want to insert data to SQL which used . (dot).

Comment: `MsgBox Range("A1").Text`

Comment: Use the Text property of the cell, instead of the Value property. Does that help?

Comment: @DavidZemens yes, it does. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Application.DecimalSeparator` affects what's *displayed* in the cell, and it's a minor, but important distinction that what's *displayed* in the cell is not always the same as the cell's `.Value` property, especially if we are tinkering with the way the value is formatted or displayed. This is apparent when using date values, for instance:

[image]

As you can see, no matter the format of the cell, the `MsgBox` function uses my (US) locale to format the date:

The exception, which is not really an exceptions, is if the `MsgBox` function is passed a string literal:

```
MsgBox(Format(#6/1/2018#,"dd-mm-yyyy"))
```

Here, we're not passing a *date*, but a string, and `MsgBox` will display that exactly per the `Format` function:

[image]

And this is kind of the same thing that's going on when you tinker with the `DecimalSeparator` or other separator properties. You haven't changed the underlying values, only the way that Excel Application represents them in the UI.

You might expect the `MsgBox` function to use the overrides that you've assigned through `Application.DecimalSeparator`, but the `MsgBox` function accepts only a `String` type for its first argument, so when you pass anything other than a string, there is an implicit conversion to string type, essentially what's happening is:

```
MsgBox(CStr(Range("A1").Value))
```

The *value* is still locale-agnostic, and now you're casting that value to a string. The only real logical output is to use the windows/system local to handle that cast.

**TL;DR**

You can use the cell's `Text` property to get at what's actually *displayed* in the cell, rather than the cell's true *value*.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot speak with 100% certainty, but I believe that while `Application.DecimalSeparator` affects what is displayed in the cell, it appears that `MsgBox` uses the Windows locale default.

What happens if you try changing it at the Windows level? Also, are you certain that your SQL inserts are not interpreting it correctly?

If needed, a potential <strike>workaround</strike> kludge might be try:

```
Dim x as Integer
Dim xs as String
x = 1.5
xs = replace(cstr(x),".", ",")
SQLString = Stuff & xs & MoreStuff
```